# Program doesn't change color

Tags: java, swing, background, jframe, paint

I'm trying to write a program where you guess a random generated number (from 1-1000) and the program will tell you if you're getting close or not. The problem I'm having is that I have to have the background change color according to how close you are to the answer. Red is closer, blue is further away. I have the code but I can't figure out why the background isn't working. Is it something to do with the container? Thank you!

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.awt.*; 
 import java.util.Random;;
 public class GuessGame extends JFrame
 {   
private JButton newGameButton;
private JButton enterButton;
private JButton exitButton;
private JTextField guessBox;
private JLabel initialTextLabel;
private JLabel enterLabel;
private JLabel userMessageLabel;
private int randomNumber;
private int userGuess;
private int counter = 0;
private int lastGuess = 0;
private Color background;
Container container;

public GuessGame()
{
    super("Guessing Game");
    newGameButton = new JButton("New Game");
    exitButton = new JButton("Exit Game");
    enterButton = new JButton("Enter");
    guessBox = new JTextField(4);
    initialTextLabel = new JLabel("I have a number between 1 and 1000 can you guess my number?");
    enterLabel = new JLabel("Please enter your first guess.");
    userMessageLabel = new JLabel("");
    randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1;

    container=getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    container.add(initialTextLabel);
    container.add(enterLabel);
    container.add(guessBox);
    container.add(newGameButton);
    container.add(enterButton);
    container.add(exitButton);
    container.add(userMessageLabel);

    setSize(400, 150);

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    newGameButtonHandler nghandler = new newGameButtonHandler();
    newGameButton.addActionListener(nghandler); 
    ExitButtonHandler exithandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
    exitButton.addActionListener(exithandler);
    enterButtonHandler enterhandler = new enterButtonHandler();
    enterButton.addActionListener(enterhandler);
}

class newGameButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        getContentPane();
        background=Color.lightGray;
        userMessageLabel.setText("");
        randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1;
    }
}

class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class enterButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        userGuess = Integer.parseInt(guessBox.getText());
        compareGuess(userGuess, randomNumber);
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    container.setBackground(background);
}

public void compareGuess(int userGuess, int randomNumber)
{
    counter++;
    if (userGuess == randomNumber)
        {
            userMessageLabel.setText("You are correct, it took you: " + counter + " tries");
            getContentPane();
            background=Color.green;
        }
    else if (userGuess > randomNumber)
        {
            userMessageLabel.setText("Too high");
        }
    else if (userGuess < randomNumber)
        {
            userMessageLabel.setText("Too Low");
        }
    if (counter > 1)
    {
        if ((randomNumber - userGuess) > (randomNumber - lastGuess))
            {
                getContentPane();
                background=Color.red;
            }
        else if ((randomNumber - userGuess) < (randomNumber - lastGuess))
            {
                getContentPane();
                background=Color.blue;
            }
        else
            {
                getContentPane();
                background=Color.gray;
            }
    }
    lastGuess = userGuess;
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    GuessGame myGuessGame = new GuessGame();
    myGuessGame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: *"I have a number between 1 and 1000 can you guess my number?"*  For the sake of easy testing, can you `System.out.println(theNumber);`?!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are trying to override `paint(Graphics g)` function of `JFrame`. We should not override paint function of Top level component like `JFrame`.
2. Use a custom component extending `JPanel` and override its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` function and don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g)` inside this function.
3. When any update should be made to the painting of a component,  invoke `component.repaint()` on that component to reflect the changes on the GUI.

Please have a tour to the Official tutorial page: [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: @BethanyBrown, all of them will help eventually. :) Please go through the linked tutorial page to know in details. It will be helpful in near future

Comment: I was able to play with it a little bit and got it to work. Like I said, #3 helped me the most (only because it got me thinking a different way haha) I like the java painting tutorial. Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 2):

I addition to Sage's comments, you are calling `setBackground` from within the `paint`, which is simply going to make another request to `paint`...again and again and again...

The other problem is, you are changing the background of the frame, not it's content pane.

Instead, get rid of your `paint` method, you're not doing anything with it...

Instead, when you want to change the color, simply call `getContentPane().setBackground(...)`, for example...

```
class newGameButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        userMessageLabel.setText("");
        randomNumber = new Random().nextInt(1000) + 1;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, you may need to call `getContentPane().repaint()`

Comment: damn i didn't even notice that. And my failure to notice made you to be *mad* +1 :)

Comment: @Sage It all builds the knowledge of the OP in the end ;)